# C++ after delete

Tags: c++

I am new to C++ and I was wondering why...

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class myClass{
    public:
        void myMethod(){
            cout << "It works!" << endl;
        }
        myClass(){
            cout << "myClass is constructed!" << endl;
        }
        ~myClass(){
            cout << "This class is destructed!" << endl;
        }
};
int main()
{
    myClass c;
    c.myMethod();
    myClass *e = &c;
    delete e;
    cout << "This is from main" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

So up there is the code. and the output is

```
myClass is constructed!
It works!
This class is destructed!
```

I am wondering where did the "This is from main" output go away.. does C++ doesn't execute codes after delete keyword?

Comment: Undefined behaviour is undefined.

Comment: I think you're getting a segmentation fault or another runtime error instead of the expected output

Comment: deleting an object you didn't new into existence leads to undefined behavior.

Comment: Remove  lines `myClass *e = &c;`  and  `delete e;` and the program will behave correctly.  c was allocated on the stack.  You can't delete from the stack!

Answer (score 9):

You can only `delete` objects that have been created with `new`.

What you're doing is UB, by the means of double deletion.

By the way, while in this case your program stopped execution right after the statement that had UB, it doesn't necessarily have to happen this way because

> However, if any such execution contains an undefined operation, this
>   International Standard places no requirement on the implementation
>   executing that program with that input (not even with regard to
>   operations preceding the first undefined operation).

Comment: So what I did is I deleted the reference of the class?

Comment: You `delete`d an instance that wasn't allocated with `new`. This is not permitted.

Comment: Oh, so this caused an error and just terminated my program. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You have undefined behavior.  You are not allowed to `delete` something that was not allocated with `new`.  In doing so you have undefined behavior and your program is allowed to do what it wants.

Most likely you should have received some sort of hard fault that stopped the program from running.

Comment: I didn't got any error though. I used cpp.sh because I wasn't home XD

Comment: Like I said you do not have to.  It is UB so nothing happening is perfectly valid.

Comment: Strictly speaking, undefined behavior does not means the program is allowed to do what it wants. Instead, it means that what the program will do is not specified at all.

Answer (score 0):

You caused undefined behavior by deleting something that was not newed.  You don't need to delete stuff that just points at some general location.  You only delete that which you created by calling `new` (not placement new!).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it is good idea for you to read about stack and heap memory.

You must free only when you malloc (or other variations such as calloc).

For example:

```
char *c = (char *)malloc(255);
...
free(c)
```

You must delete only if you use new.

```
MyClass *e = new MyClass()
... 
delete e
```

You must delete[] only if you use new[]

```
char *data = new char[20]
...
delete[] data
```

Now, if you do something like this:

```
...
{
  int x;
  x = 3;
}
```

x will be destroyed after the bracers because it is out of scope. This puts x on the stack. However, if you use malloc, new, or delete, the variable itself can be lost if you are not careful, but the memory is allocated. This is memory leak.

What you have is even more dangerous. You are deleting something which was not allocated. The behavior is not defined. With time and patience, a skilled hacker can study the behavior and may be able to break into your system and acquire same privileges as your program.